# Combine two XMLnodelist in VBA

Tags: excel, nodelist, vba

I have to XMLnodelists which is want to combine to one.
So I would like to copy the content of oNodelist_B into oNodeList_A

```
Set oNodeList_A = xmldoc.getElementsByTagName("A")
Set oNodeList_B = xmldoc.getElementsByTagName("B")
```

anyone have an idea.?

Comment: What's the ultimate purpose?  What do you want to do with the combined list?

Comment: Hi Tim, The reason is, i have a tool which i need to update. This tool analyze data which is in oNodeList_A (Input for this list is a XML file). The update what i want to do it to add different data in this list, from the xm file. So beside getElementByTagName (“A”) , also (“B’). That why i was thinking to fill two different node lists and then combine them into one. Maybe you have an idea to do this? Or different solution?

Comment: @TimWilliams see comment above

Comment: If you use xpath to select your nodes then you can use the union operator `|` in your xpath expression.

Comment: @TimWilliams , Tim Thank you very much for your replay. I tried to use xpath expression, but I struggle with the combination.
The code:
Set oNodeList = xmlDoc.SelectNodes("//A") and  Set oNodeList = xmlDoc.SelectNodes("//B") are working separately fine. But I do not know how to combine the A and B together. Because I tried to use the | char. But is result that only the nodes from A will be filled in the nodelist.
This is what I tried:
Set oNodeList = xmlDoc.SelectNodes("//A|B")

Answer (score 1):

This works for me:

```
Sub Tester()
   Dim xmlDoc As New MSXML2.DOMDocument30
   Dim objNodes As IXMLDOMNodeList, o As IXMLDOMElement

  xmlDoc.async = False

  'xmlDoc.Load "D:\Analysis\config.xml"
  xmlDoc.LoadXML Range("A1").Value

  xmlDoc.setProperty "SelectionLanguage", "XPath" '<< required!

  If xmlDoc.parseError.errorCode <> 0 Then

    MsgBox "Error!" & vbCrLf & _
    "  Line: " & xmlDoc.parseError.Line & vbCrLf & _
    "  Text:" & xmlDoc.parseError.srcText & vbCrLf & _
    "  Reason: " & xmlDoc.parseError.reason

  Else

    Set objNodes = xmlDoc.SelectNodes("root/A|root/B")
    If objNodes.Length = 0 Then
      Debug.Print "not found"
    Else
      For Each o In objNodes
        Debug.Print o.tagName, o.nodeTypedValue
      Next o
    End If

  End If

End Sub
```

Test XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root>
     <A>ValA1</A>
     <A>ValA2</A>
     <B>ValB1</B>
     <B>ValB2</B>
</root>
```